# Keeping Vue Router alive with Vue router links in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-router

Whenever I route between two views, the first view components are all reset! is there a way to keep the states of the first view without reset while routing? thanks in advance.

```html
<div>
  <div id="titleControl">
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'controls' }" class="tablink borderLink">
      Controls
    </router-link>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'logs' }" class="tablink borderLink">
      Logs
    </router-link>
  </div>

  <router-view />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution for this is wrapping the `<router-view>` inside the `<KeepAlive>` component.

Comment: I get this warning: `[Vue Router warn]: <router-view> can no longer be used directly inside <transition> or <keep-alive>. Use slot props instead: <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">  <keep-alive>   <component :is="Component" />  </keep-alive> </router-view> vue-router.mjs:35`

Comment: An issue on GitHub has been reported regarding this- https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/1306

Comment: And one more answer you can look into it for this warning- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70848012/vue3-router-transitions-warnings